# can we able to identify whether the http (post) request is modified before reaching to server?

Tags: java, struts2

I want to validate HTTP (post) request whether the request is being modified or not. I am Using Struts-2 framework and java.

Comment: That's what HTTPS is for.

Comment: but when i modify request using Burp Suit  how do i get to know

Comment: That's the point - with HTTPS, you can't modify a request, because the request will be encrypted.